# How to substitute specific positions using regex and lists?

Tags: python, string, python-re

lets say I have the following string in Python:

```
s = "Hi, I currently have 2 apples and 3 oranges"
```

in regex we can do

```
r = re.findall(r'\d',s)
```

and this would give us a list containing the numbers:
`["2","3"]`

However, lets say I want to substitute these numbers using a list in the order that they appear in the sentence.

```
new_list = ["4","5"]
```

and make the new sentences say:

> "Hi, I currently have **4** apples and **5** oranges"

I tried doing the following:

```
new_sentence = [re.sub(('\d'),x, s) for x in new_list]
```

But that gave me:

```
['Hi, I currently have 4 apples and 4 oranges', 'Hi, I currently have 5 apples and 5 oranges']
```

Which is not what I wanted. How do you substitute values using regex in the order that they appear using a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an iterator from the `new_list` and use it in `re.sub`:

```py
import re


s = "Hi, I currently have 2 apples and 3 oranges"
new_list = ["4", "5"]

new_list_iter = iter(new_list)

out = re.sub(r"\d+", lambda _: next(new_list_iter), s)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
Hi, I currently have 4 apples and 5 oranges
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution

```
''.join(map( operator.add, 
             re.split('\d+', s), 
             ['4','5']+[''] 
))
```

When map receives multiple iterables like this, it starts by sending the first item from the two iterables as parameters to the `operator.add` function, and then the next two items, and so on. We have to add an empty string to the end  of the replacement values to make it the same length as `re.split`.